# A nil value specializationUtil LUA

Tags: lua

I'm trying to convert fs17 to fs19 mouse steering mod.

Console shows up:

```
register.lua:11: attempt to call field 'registerSpecialization' (a nil value)
```

Code look like this:

```
SpecializationUtil.registerSpecialization("ControlMouse", "ControlMouse", g_currentModDirectory.."ControlMouse.lua")

ControlMouse_Register = {};
```

I tried to solve it by:

```
if SpecializationUtil.specializations["ControlMouse"] == nil then
   SpecializationUtil.registerSpecialization("ControlMouse", "ControlMouse", g_currentModDirectory.."ControlMouse.lua");
   addSpecialization.isLoaded = false;
else
   -- print("  mod controlmouse is loaded!");
end;
```

After that it show this:

```
/mods/ControlMouse/register.lua:1: attempt to index field 'specializations' (a nil value)
```

Thanks for solution.
If you want I'll send you full code

Answer (score 0):

try to check SpecializationUtil:

```
if SpecializationUtil ~= nil then
  -- do
end
```